openstreetmap how to call for return gps coordinate?
Hi i try to reverse strett to gps coordinate in openstreetmap i try to do that with this string
curl "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=Via+Bruno+Buozzi+18,+Fucecchio+Firenze&format=json"

but not work,not return nothing, but i read a manual and i suppose i compose a string correctly
i try  also with out a province curl
"https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=Via+Bruno+Buozzi+18,+Fucecchio&format=json"

but nothing anyone have idea how compose that ?

The search results are simply empty. Either this address doesn't exist or the address format you specified wasn't understood. It seems like the latter is true, reducing it to "Via Bruno Buozzi 18, Firenze" instead returns results:
https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/ui/search.html?q=Via+Bruno+Buozzi+18%2C+Firenze

thanks in florence  work  , right  but via bruno buozzi exist also in fucecchio  and  fucecchio is under firenze , how is possible find  viabruno buozzi in fucecchio ? i try to substitute  firenze with fucecchio but noyhing. os.exist via bruno buozzi 18 in fucecchio i can see in google map ...

There is no "Via Bruno Buozzi" in Fucecchio. However, there is a "Viale Bruno Buozzi" in Fucecchio. Searching for it works as expected: https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/ui/search.html?q=Viale+Bruno+Buozzi%2C+Fucecchio. Nominatim can't handle typos, it has no auto-correction. If you need a search engine that can handle minor errors, try Photon instead: https://photon.komoot.io/
